Which representation of $\mathrm{SL} (2; \mathbb{C})$ does the tautological bundle on $ \mathbb{CP}^1 $ correspond to?
If I understand correctly, by Borel-Weil-Bott, for each weight of $\mathrm{SL} (2; \mathbb{C})$ there is a corresponding (holomorphic) line bundle / invertible sheaf on $ \mathbb{CP}^1 $. Denoting the weights as integers, we can see that for $ n \geq 0 $ we get the line bundle $ \mathcal{O} (n) $, and for $ n < 0 $ we get $ \mathcal{O} (n-2) $.
In contrast, there seems to be no weight corresponding to $ \mathcal{O} (-2) $ (for which $H^1$ is the trivial representation); and arguably even stranger, there is no weight corresponding to the tautological bundle $ \mathcal{O} (-1) $ (which has zero cohomology in all dimensions). You might argue that Borel-Weil-Bott does not guarantee a one-to-one correspondence between weights and line bundles. However, there is a more general theorem (for which it is strangely difficult to find a textbook reference) stating that:
$$ \mathrm{Sh}_G \left( G/B \right) \cong \mathrm{Rep} \left( B \right) $$
i.e., the category of $G$-equivariant sheaves on the space $G/B$ is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional representations of $B$. I am not entirely sure what are the necessary conditions on the groups $G$ and $B$ here (it is definitely sufficient for $G$ to be finite), but I am fairly certain that it holds in our case, i.e. for $ G = \mathrm{SL} (2; \mathbb{C}) $ and $B$ a Borel subgroup. If we need $G$ to be compact, we can take $ G = \mathrm{SU} (2) $ and $B=T$ its maximal torus.
Either way, we see that any $G$-equivariant sheaf on $ \mathbb{CP}^1 $ should uniquely correspond to some representation of $B$; and I would expect a line bundle to correspond to a one-dimensional representation, hence to a weight. However, $ \mathcal{O} (-1) $ does not seem to correspond to any nonzero representation. It seems that at least one of my assumptions here is false, so my question is: which one?

My understanding of this theory comes solely from the side of algebraic groups. Indeed, line bundles on $G/B$ give rise to representations of $G$. I have seen the connection described as the space of global sections. But $G=SL_2(\Bbb{C})$, the homogeneous space $G/B$ is the Riemann sphere. And the line bundles corresponding to negative weights simply have no global sections, and hence would yield the trivial 0-dimensional representation.

(cont'd) On the Lie algebra side we can form a Verma-module using a negative (more generally, non-dominant) highest weight. The heads of those are all infinite dimensional. I'm not sure if they can also be interpreted in terms of line bundles.

All the weights do give rise to a 1-dimensional representation of $B$, but how to get a rep of $G$? The route via line bundles can also be described as an induction (in terms of representation theory, so attempting to lift a rep of a subgroup to a bigger group), but that won't do anything here. Precisely because the vectors in the induced representation are global sections of the sheaf on $G/B$. Higher cohomology gives something non-zero with non-dominant weights, and that game is very interesting in characteristic $p>0$. IIRC in char $0$ we simply get the same (classical) f.d. reps again.

I think everything is OK, indeed $G$-equivariant sheaves are equivalent to representations of $B$, but $G$-equivariant sheaves are not equivalent to representations of $G$ - they just give rise to them via cohomology, which can be sometimes zero.

I was not expecting to get "other" representations of $G$; as @JyrkiLahtonen said, the bundles corresponding to negative weights give rise to the same f.d. irreps as positive weights, but in the first cohomology instead of the global sections.
My question was - if the correspondence between sheaves on $G/B$ and reps of $B$ is true, then any two non-isomorphic sheaves should give rise to distinct reps of $B$. So which reps of $B$ correspond to $\mathcal{O} (-1)$ and $\mathcal{O} (-2)$?

The last part of the first statement is false; for any $n$, we get $\mathcal{O}(n)$ as the line bundle $\mathcal{L}_{-n}$ associated to weight $-n$ (along with a $G-$equivariant structure). The statement of Borel-Weyl-Bott (for example, as stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Weil%E2%80%93Bott_theorem) then tells you that:

If $n$ is singular for the shifted Weyl group action, which in the $SL_2$ case is the same as the case n=-1, then all cohomology groups are zero.
If $n>-1$, i.e., n is dominant, then the cohomology is concentrated in degree 0 and the action of $SL_2$ on the global sections precisely recovers action of $SL_2$ on the irrep associated to highest weight $n$.
If $n<-1$ (not dominant, non-singular case), then the simple reflection $s$ in the Weyl group $S_2$ takes n to a dominant weight, and Borel-Weyl-Bott tells you that the cohomology is concentrated in degree 1 (since length(s)=1) and corresponds to the irrep of $Sl_2$ with highest weight $s*n=s(n+1)-1= -n-1-1=-n-2$. So for example, $\mathcal{O}(-2)$ recovers the trivial rep as the first cohomology group, $\mathcal{O}(-3)$ the standard rep etc.

If you're interested in the explicit $SL_2$ action on these line bundles, take a look at Section 9.11 (pg 255) of D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves and Representation Theory by Hotta, Takeuchi, Tanisaki. They also provide the explicit correspondence between $G-$equivariant vector bundles on $G/B$ and $B-$equivariant vector bundles on a point (which is the same as a representation of $B$). I should warn you that the shifted action is slightly different there, causing the statements to vary a bit from the Wikipedia, where they take the line bundle $\mathcal{L}_n$ associated to $n$ instead of $\mathcal{L}_{-n}$ etc., but still yields the same explicit results as above.
Edit: From your comments, it seems that you're asking how to go from a $G-$equivariant vector bundle to a representation of $B$. This is again in Section 9.11 of the book by Hotta, Takeuchi, Tanisaki, and is done as follows. Let $E\rightarrow G/B$ be the $G$-equivariant vector bundle and let $E_{B/B}$ be the fiber over the point $\{B/B\}\hookrightarrow G/B$. This is a vector space and is stable under the $B-$action, hence gives you a representation of $B$. If you take the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(n)$, this recovers the one dimensional representation of $B$ which acted on via weight $-n$. Borel-Weyl-Bott is actually telling you how the irreps of $G$ are encoded in the cohomology of these $G-$equivariant line bundles.

I think I have finally understood the source of my confusion (thanks to I'm Representable!). Indeed there is a one-to-one correspondence between weights and line bundles (slightly shifting conventions): to each weight $n$ there is a corresponding line bundle $\mathcal{L}_{-n}$, which is the invertible sheaf $ \mathcal{O} \left(n \right) $. In particular, the tautological sheaf $ \mathcal{O} \left(-1 \right) $ corresponds to the weight $1$, the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ corresponds to the weight $0$, and $ \mathcal{O} \left(1 \right) $ corresponds to the weight $-1$. Indeed, an element of $ B$ acts on the fiber of $ \mathcal{O} \left(-n \right) $ at $ \left[ 1 : 0 \right] $ as follows:
$$ b = \begin{bmatrix}
z & x \\
0 & z^{-1}
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
a \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
z^n \cdot a \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} $$
so the equivalence holds.
However, only for dominant weights $n \geq 0$ do we get that the representation of $ \mathrm{SL} \left( 2 ; \mathbb{C} \right) $ constructed by Borel-Weil-Bott is the one corresponding to the maximal weight $n$. For $n<0$ the representations of $B$ on the fibers are still the ones corresponding to the weight $n$, but these are no longer related to the representations of $ \mathrm{SL} \left( 2 ; \mathbb{C} \right) $ constructed by BWB.
